# Is there a way to get input value from php DOMdocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument, getelementbyid

I want to get the value of an input field without _POST (form) method, instead using DOMdocument. But it didn't seem to work. Here is my HTML code and PHP code.

```
<div class="calc">
      <h1 id="title">Calculator</h1>
      <input type="number" id="num1" class="field">
      <br>
      +
      <br>
      <input type="number" id="num2" class="field">
      <br>
      =
      <br>
      <input type="number" id="result" class="field" readonly>
 </div>
```

php:

```
<?php

 // Create a new DOM Document
 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
 
 // Enable validate on parse
 $dom->validateOnParse = true;
 
 // Create a div element
 $element = $dom->appendChild(new DOMElement('div',
 '<div id="calc">Hey, this is the text content of the div element.</div>'));
 
 // Get the tag content
 $num1content = $dom->getElementById('num1')->textContent;
 
 echo $num1content;

 ?>
```

Note: All of this is in the same file

Comment: As this is all done in one file, the whole script is run before being displayed to the user. This also mean it's processed before the user can enter anything.

Comment: thanks but how do I make it echo auto when the user types?

Comment: You can't do that with PHP, do it with javascript (that runs on client-side).